# Counterexample of $\Bbb Q_p$ is sequentially compact?

Tags: number-theory, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

I have heard **$\Bbb Q_p$ is sequentially compact**, in other word, every sequence of $\Bbb Q_p$ must have convergent subsequence.
But I think I cannot take convergent subsequence from infinite sequence $p,1/p,1/p^2,1/p^3, ...$.

Where am I missing ? Could you tell me the convergent subsequence of $p,1/p,1/p^2,1/p^3, ...$?

Comment: $ 1/p $ is not a $ p $-adic integer.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Then, this sequence gives the example of p-adic field is not compact ?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450345/show-that-z-p-is-sequentially-compact) for $\Bbb Z_p$, your original question. For $\Bbb Q_p$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122493/show-that-mathbbq-p-is-locally-compact).

Comment: The post seems not answer my question. Is Qp compact?(not locally compact)

Comment: The field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not compact. The sequence you gave $(1/p^{n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not have a convergent subsequence. The ring of integers (and hence unit ball) $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is, however, compact and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is locally compact as a result.