Is the $p$-adic unit sphere compact?
Let $p$ be a (nonzero) prime integer, and let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the standard field of $p$-adic numbers with the standard $p$-adic norm $||\cdot||$.
Let $S := \{ x \in \mathbb{Q}_p : ||x||=1\}$ be the "$p$-adic unit sphere".

I am wondering whether $S$ is compact?
(I asked ChatGPT, which said $S$ is noncompact, though the proof it suggested was missing many parts, so I'm not sure if it is valid.)
Also, if I'm not mistaken, the following argument seems to imply $S$ is compact?

We can express $S$ as a level set of the norm function $\mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} : x \mapsto ||x||$, which is continuous; hence $S$ is closed in any subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ containing $S$.

In particular $S$ is a closed subset of the origin-centered closed unit ball $B:= \{ x \in \mathbb{Q}_p : ||x||\leq 1\}$, and B is known to be compact (see this MSE post); hence $S$ is compact.



So far I haven't been able to find an explanation about this online; would anyone have a suggestion for a reference that discusses this?

Have you asked ChatGPT for an explanation? I don't think that MSE is the right forum for publishing specific issues with ChatGPT's pronouncements on mathematical questions.

I did and it didn't really seem to explain anything properly. Either way, I can remove the part about ChatGPT if it is unwanted. I only included it to clarify what resources I've tried so far

I see. I think you'll find that the underlying mathematical question has been answered on MSE before (see the answer from Jacques below or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122493/show-that-mathbbq-p-is-locally-compact).

@RobArthan I already referenced this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78449/why-are-closed-balls-in-the-p-adic-topology-compact) which is more directly related to my query. Anyway, my question was mainly about whether my proof that a compact closed unit ball implies a compact unit sphere is valid. I already found a fairly easy proof as described in my question, but I just wanted to check if it was valid with MSE, since ChatGPT disagreed with my answer.

So your question isn't a reference request but rather a proof verification request. I think you need to rethink the question.

@RobArthan The question is already answered, but I will try to phrase it differently next time. I've also changed the tags to remove "reference-request" and add "proof-verification".

Asking to account for the pronouncements of any LLM on mathematics is like asking to debunk endless crazy things on the internet. :)

@paulgarrett Oh I wasn't asking for an explanation of why ChatGPT said what it did, I've heard of other such cases before where ChatGPT says complete nonsense when asked abstract mathematical questions. I just wanted to confirm that ChatGPT's answer to my question was wrong. I liked the comparison you made though

You're right. Since $S$ is a closed subset of the unit ball which is compact, it is compact. Note that the unit ball is actually the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$. These notes seem to cover the subject, especially Theorem 6.4.
